# how to create Rtl ViewPager for locale?

Tags: android

How to create **Rtl ViewPager** with both **En** and **Arabic** locale?

I am using this code :

https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager

but i cannot implement both locale.

Comment: More info.Add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this line](https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager/blob/master/rtlviewpager/src/main/java/com/booking/rtlviewpager/RtlViewPager.java#L141) in RtlViewPager's source. It controls whether the `RtlViewPager` is in right-to-left mode.

If you extend `RtlViewPager` and override this method to always return `true`, the English locale should also appear as RTL.

For example:

```
public class AlwaysRtlViewPager extends RtlViewPager {
    public AlwaysRtlViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AlwaysRtlViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRtl() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Just replace your usages of RtlViewPager with this sub-class and you should get the desired result.

Comment: Sir , how to create any Fragment in this code : [link] (https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager)   ,     can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any third party library. Android jetpack recently added new UI component called ViewPager2 which supports RTL Layout.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2

The below answer talks about Migration guide and sample github app to support RTL view pager.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59558911/651377